# Setting Values for Invisible Fields/Properties in DetailsView

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq-to-entities, detailsview

I have a DetailsView which has two fields - one that is visible, one that is not. The first the user fills out, the second I want to auto-populate. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find a way to set the value in this second invisible field. I've tried adding code like this to the Page_Load:

```
 If Not IsPostBack Then
        DetailsView1.DefaultMode = DetailsViewMode.Insert
        Dim txt1 As TextBox = DirectCast(DetailsView1.FindControl("Type"), TextBox)
        txt1.Text = "administrator"
 End If
```

But this returns an error of "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." Any ideas on how to accomplish this - either using the method above or another method?

The hoped for end result is that when a new record is inserted via the DetailsView that this record will include the username (entered by the user) as well as the "type" of "administrator"

Comment: How did you bind the DetailsView? LindDataSource, ObjectDataSource, SQLDataSource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the style of the controls :

```
style="visibility: hidden; height: 0"
```

That way the browser will not show them.

If you set the controls on the server to invisible, there will be no html rendered.

**Edit:**
You could also use a hidden field:

```
<asp:HiddenField runat=server Value="SomeValue" />
```

But, it may be better to keep the information on the server, in a session variable or something. Information in hidden fields on the client can be compoimised).

Comment: @davemackey: Don't use that solution. I'll post a real solution this evening or tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

the way I solved this when I had this problem was by making the control visible and putting it behind a panel or another control.

Comment: Thanks. I'm hoping I don't have to do that, but if it comes down to it... :)

Comment: @davemackey: You won't have to